# How do I call a method when an image has been fully loaded and rendered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to call a method after an image has been loaded and fully rendered in the browser.

Quick example for a big image:

http://jsfiddle.net/2cLm4epv/

```
<img width="500px" src="http://www.digivill.net/~binary/wall-covering/(huge!)14850x8000%2520earth.jpg">
```

My method should be called when the picture is fully visible.

Comment: `$('.thatImage').load(function(){ //code here });`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I am trying smt like this http://jsfiddle.net/2cLm4epv/4/   but does not work

Comment: @GibboK Use this http://jsfiddle.net/2cLm4epv/5/ I think the reason for why your fiddle not working is the invalid html. Image tag should be a self closable one.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy please add it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: I have a similar question here, any suggestion is very appreciate thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215434/how-to-call-a-method-when-an-image-has-been-loaded-and-rendered-after-adding-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments use the `.load()` function along with its call back to accomplish your task,

**HTML**

```
<img id="bigimage" width="500px" src="http://www.digivill.net/~binary/wall-covering/(huge!)14850x8000%2520earth.jpg"/>
```

**JS**

```
$('#bigimage').load(function(){
    alert('loaded and redered');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2cLm4epv/5/)